# Getting Date Values from Inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

Here i am unable to get date of birth, it shows error after that

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddDetailsToList()

    Dim YourName As String
    Dim YourDoB As Date
    Dim YouAre As String
    Dim YouWant As String
    Dim NextBlank As Range
    Dim tryagain As Integer

   YourName = InputBox("Enter your name")

   YourDoB = InputBox("Enter your date of birth")

   If YourDoB = Date Then

    YouAre = InputBox("You are a:")
    YouWant = InputBox("You're looking for a:")

    Set NextBlank = Sheet2.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    With NextBlank
        .Value = YourName
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = YourDoB
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = YouAre
        .Offset(0, 3).Value = YouWant
    End With

    Else

   tryagain = MsgBox("invalid value! Try again?", vbYesNo)

    If tryagain = 6 Then
    AddDetailsToList

    End If
    End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting and on which line? Please edit your question and include that information. Keep in mind that `InputBox` always returns a `String` - So to get a date, you have to get it as a `String` first, and then convert it to a date, assuming the user enters a valid date.

Comment: Hi Shivam, my bet is that the format of your date string is incorrect.See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589099/vba-convert-string-to-date

Comment: @braX As you can see that i have used On Error statement above this line:YouAre = InputBox("You are a:") which redirects the code to a separate section of the subroutine when a user tries to type in an invalid date. ie.  Else

   tryagain = MsgBox("invalid value! Try again?", vbYesNo)

    If tryagain = 6 Then
    AddDetailsToList.

Comment: Yes, but your if statement is checking to see if the "date" they entered is today's date, which of course it will never be as newborns wont be running the code.

Comment: @braX Also I  have used the correct date format .. for eg: mm/dd/yyyy or mm/dd/yy.In fact i have used every other date format,but again and again , i encountered :same error ,please try again!

Comment: As previously stated:  `InputBox` always returns a `String` - Your variable is not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
If YourDoB = Date Then
```

to this:

```
If IsDate(YourDoB) Then
```

The line you entered was checking if the entered text is today's date. The line I've provided checks to see if the entered text is a date.

Also, change this line

```
.Offset(0, 1).Value = YourDoB
```

to this:

```
.Offset(0, 1).Value = cdate(YourDoB)
```

That will make sure that the value is stored as a date in that cell, rather than text.

Comment: Probably should change this too: `Dim YourDoB As Date`

Comment: @judge  you are awesome man  really!!  Thanks a lot!! That works perfectly  :)